# Segmentation of Signature from Image with varying background colour

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am trying to extract Image from a pan card with is ID card in India. Trying to extract the same with OpenCV and python. I have tried out the same using connected components background is interfering with it too much.

This is the sample input

[image]

This is the required output

[image]

I have followed [this  project](https://github.com/ahmetozlu/signature_extractor) as initial starting pointing, but not able to extract the same properly
because of the gradient in the background.
Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point let me know in the comments.

Comment: Is the input always going to be nicely cropped like this ?

Comment: Have you taken into account the fact that in ID card like this, for everyone, the signature is placed at the same location in the ID card. Thus, you can directly extract the ROI of the signature and then whatever text is present there, you can extract it by thresholding as the signature is always the darkest thing in that region. I think this will solve your problem at once.

Comment: No, The signature shifts position in the bottom left to bottom right.  There are various types all having the same background but the position of the signature and photo seems to move around a bit for example [[ another pancard](https://4.imimg.com/data4/ED/PP/ANDROID-46085837/product-500x500.jpeg)]

Comment: Another thing that you can do is find the text in the image... the region with text detected below a certain confidence threshold will be approximately the signature area.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that there are many types of same ID card. To deal with this, you can detect the type of card in the image and then extract the corresponding region. Another thing you can try is to find the text "Signature" in the card... definitely above this, you will have the signature and thus get the ROI.

Comment: @RahulKedia when signature moves the text to comes to action and the round thing in the background also becomes a dark part and interferes with the signature. The text-based extraction is not possible since its very small fir OCR seems to not work. I was using tesseract for the OCR

Comment: You are thresholding using which colour scale?

Comment: @RahulKedia I was using Yen thresholding from scikit image. I didn't use a  color-based thresholding as such. But I used the green channel for the Thresholding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221508/discussion-between-nithin-varghese-and-rahul-kedia).

Answer (score 2):

Adaptive thresholding on the blue component seems to do the job easily.[image]

Comment: @NithinVarghese: this was made with proprietary software. Adaptive thresholding is available in OpenCV.

Comment: would please point me out the steps you take for the final output and the specific parameter for Adaptive thresholding

Comment: @NithinVarghese: convert to grayscale and apply adaptive thresholding. This is two lines. Try different parameters.

Comment: should I use connected components to the segment Signature from the output of Adaptive thresholding?

Comment: @NithinVarghese: I don't know. That depends on what you need to do with this signature.

Comment: What kind of segmentation did you use for the above answer. I've to save the result in a file. This used for some other ml pipeline.

Comment: @NithinVarghese: there is no segmentation there.